# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'groot'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, laravel, shared-hosting

My laravel app is running fine on localhost. When I have put it on shared hosting. It shows the following errors.
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'groot'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: insert into `clients`.........

The shared hosting has disabled ssh. I can do anything only manually. Please suggest me what to do?
Thanks

Comment: check your `.env` file. did you create `user` and `database` in **CPANEL MySQL® Databases** ? , and did you add `created user` to `created_database` ???

Comment: check `.env` is your mysql host, username and password is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems.

1. Wrong DB_HOST
2. Wrong DB_USER
3. Wrong DB_PASSWORD

Make sure all of them are correct and you have enough privileges to connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database.php file.
Clear cache and config using after updating the password in .env file and database.php file

```
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

The .env file on your local computer should have different configurations with the one on the shared hosting. I can see you are using localhost on your hosting.
Check the .env and make sure these correspond to the servers you are hosting on

```
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```